# why it gives me a compilation error:Cannot reduce the visibility of the inherited method from DeclareStuff

Tags: java, visibility

```
1interface DeclareStuff {
2    public static final int EASY = 3;
3    void doStuff(int t); }
4    public class TestDeclare implements DeclareStuff {
5    public static void main(String [] args) {
6    int x = 5;
7    new TestDeclare().doStuff(++x);
8    }
9    void doStuff(int s) {
10   s += EASY + ++s;
     System.out.println("s " + s);
     }
     }
```

why it gives me a compilation error:Cannot reduce the visibility of the inherited method from DeclareStuff  ,at the line 9,that is at void doStuffe(int s).

Answer (score 12):

Interface methods are implicitly `public`. Implementations of interface methods must also always be `public`.

The compiler error is telling you that you cannot make a implementation of a method "less" visible than its supertype. Your class's method has default visibility, which is "less" visible than the `public` method of the interface.

So make `TestDeclare.doStuff` a `public` method, and it'll work.